# Запустить при помощи Python .exe программу, которая, в свою очередь, запустит файл на выполнение

Tags: python, subprocess

Есть iasl.exe программа, которая генерирует из скомпилированного "0 raw section.bin" файла исходный. В командной строке запуск выглядит так:

> iasl.exe "0 raw section.bin"

Проблема в том, что таких файлов дофига и хочется написать скрипт, который бы автоматически генерировал эти самые файлы. Знаю про модуль subprocess, но использовать не приходилось.

По факту нужно что-то типа

> subprocess.call('iasl.exe 0 raw section.bin')

но такая штука не работает. И вообще подскажите пожалуйста пример, где открывается .ехе программа и ей скармливается какой-либо файл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно сделать просто так

```
from os import system
system('iasl.exe "0 raw section.bin"')
```

или попробовать через subprocess

```
subprocess.call(["/path/to/iasl.exe","0 raw section.bin" ])
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!
А где должен находиться 0 raw section.bin? К нему можно прописать абсолютный путь? И сколько таких .bin можно передавать?

Comment: Можно написать абсолютний путь. По сути говоря subprocess.call запускает такой же процесс как и сmd, только вместо пробелов надо использывать елементы списка. (subprocess.call(['program.exe', 'arg1' , 'arg2', 'arg3']) делает то же самое что и  "program.exe arg1 arg2 arg3")

Comment: 1 можно написать абсолютый путь
2 можно запускать код из директории с с файликами bin
3 можно добавить директории с bin  в системную переменную PATH
по поводу количиства, если честно не помню, но всегда можно обернуть в цикл и использовать только 1 аргумент.